# Faster PHP or Shell script for collecting data?

Tags: php

Which would be faster and less resources, invoking a shell script that collect data from a third party site via PHP and then phrasing it in PHP for the user or using PHP to do the collecting and phrasing for the user?

Its not a huge amount of data, simple user profile migration script, but the user starts the process.

Comment: That depends on the implementation.

Comment: I agree with @deceze. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a user operation, I would probably keep it in PHP. This of course depends upon your specific case but like you said, it's a simple script so keep it simple.